# How to save tweets of another user?

Tags: twitter

How can I save all tweets of a user?

For webpage, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the whole webpage. For Twitter, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the tweets of a user, you can quite easily use [**the Twitter API**](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline). Note that this method can only return up to **3,200** of a user’s most recent Tweets.

As a 3rd party app, there is ExportTweet.

**< 2024 Mod Edit >**Since late 2019 ExportTweet ([Web Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190816221520/https://www.exporttweet.com/)) has been redirected to spam sites.**</ 2024 Mod Edit >**

> With ExportTweet you can download public tweets of any user.
> ExportTweet also provide option to setup the scheduler to download
> user tweets in selective interval.

Ian Anderson Gray wrote in part in his 2013 [Quora answer, "Can I archive someone else's tweets?"](https://qr.ae/pKqcin):

> It's currently not possible to access more than the last 3,200 tweets
> due to limits on the API imposed by Twitter. In [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20131021132339/https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/276) it
> is said that capacity and infrastructrure issues are to blame. Twitter
> do store older tweets, and in fact all tweets going back to the
> beginning, it's just you can't access this from the timeline. You can,
> however, access an older tweet by knowing it's ID. Technically it
> could be possible to build a database of older tweets just by
> accessing them by the ID, but the resulting database would be huge,
> and go against Twitter's terms.
>
> There are archiving tools available but all that I have found require
> OAUTH access, which as I mentioned in my question is no good if you
> are trying to archive someone else's account.